# Enabling nginx Chunked Transfer Encoding

Tags: nginx, chunked-encoding

It looks like [nginx 0.8.35 may support chunked transfer encoding](http://nginx.org/en/CHANGES):

> Changes with nginx 0.8.35                                        01 Apr 2010
>
> ```
> *) Change: now the charset filter runs before the SSI filter.
>
> *) Feature: the "chunked_transfer_encoding" directive.
> ```

This is great, because I'm trying to get push git changes through an nginx reverse proxy to a git-http-backend process. Git HTTP takes advantage of chunked transfer encoding [for client-side efficiency reasons](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2008/8/3/2795094).

However, I can't get it to work. I'm using nginx 0.8.44 on Debian Lenny with the following configure invocation:

```
./configure \
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--user=www-data \
--group=www-data \
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
--lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock \
--with-http_ssl_module \
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-http_realip_module
```

And the following conf file:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass  http://192.168.0.10;
        include     /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
        chunked_transfer_encoding on;
    }
}
```

And my `proxy.conf` looks like this:

```
proxy_redirect          off;
proxy_set_header        Host $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size    100M;
client_body_buffer_size 128k;
proxy_connect_timeout   90;
proxy_send_timeout      90;
proxy_read_timeout      90;
proxy_buffer_size       4k;
proxy_buffers           4 32k;
proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe chunked_transfer_encoding is on by default.  The configuration flag works properly when added to the server{} scope and is not valid when placed in the location{} scope.