# What exactly does a HTTP or jquery $.ajax timeout mean?

Tags: ajax, http

When I issue an `$.ajax` query with a `timeout:` parameter, and my `timeout` is met such that `error:` is invoked, what does that mean?

More specifically:
 does that mean the server received the request, but is still processing it? That may mean some effect may occur, so I may have to cancel it on the server, or somehow invalidate data that was already partially written to a database.

Or does that mean I was never able to reach the server at all? This is nice to know since then I don't have to deal with partial data on a server "save"

Or does that mean the request made it part of the way, and now we lost track of it? In this case, I'd have to actually ask the server, "Oh hey, about that request I sent awhile ago... did you get that one? yeah? okay ignore that last save"

OS Commands like `tracert` make it clear there  may be many servers for a TCP command to go through, so if one becomes unresponsive, it's hard to tell if it got it or not. But some protocols require an echo-back to be considered receivable (so I'm not sure if HTTP or Apache is involved in this)

Comment: It should not be possible to write partial data to the database in the first place. If you need to e.g. insert over multiple table start a transaction

Comment: Yes, unless you write data over multiple AJAX requests (which is of course, unadvisable). This is likely to happen for batch file uploads or something where you may be creating thumbnails server side or having to post the file data seperately because it is so large

Comment: Nobody should ever do that / does that because it makes no sense to allow data to be in an inconsistent state like that. "because it is so large" Wut? How large?

Comment: Depends on how big the data is. If your data is 1.5GB, then are you really saying you should do that in  one request?

Comment: Yes that is what I am saying

Comment: What if you want it to be resumable? If it fails at 1.4GB, and it's one request, you can't resume

Comment: Yes you can http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19907628/transfer-encoding-chunked

Comment: BTW it's really hard to guess what your actual quetsion is, because your comments say something different than your question

Comment: My comments are merely hypothetical, the question is more general. Theres a lot of server-side implications beside database-writes which are interesting, such as session storage, client side assumptions, local storage, cookies, tokens, UI state, and on and on. But I did learn about chunked HTTP transfer which was interesting. The specific reality I'm facing is lots of data uploaded over mobile phones using specially installed amplifying antennaes in remote areas causing lots of timeouts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is how long the client will wait to hear from the server before giving up.

The server may or may not have done its part.  The only way for the client to know about that is for the client to be notified.  Since you don't want to to leave a process or a human waiting forever, by using a timeout you specify the time to wait for success before giving up.

Comment: Okay that's what I figured. Due to physical limitations (such as line of sight radio) this makes the most sense.