# HTTP Yield Response - is this technically possible?

Tags: php

Is this technically possible to make Response Generator by using PHP, AJAX, JS?

For example:

```
// php
foreach(range(0,1000,100) as $range) {
    yieldResponse('My range is: $range <br>');
    sleep(1);
}
```

Browser user would see this response:

```
My range is: 0
```

After 1 second:

```
My range is: 0
My range is: 100
```

After 5 seconds:

```
My range is: 0
My range is: 100
My range is: 200
My range is: 300
My range is: 400
My range is: 500
```

In other words:

Is this possible to send parts of responses in loop before end of php script and without stop this scripts?

Comment: Yes it is possible with `AJAX`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20718531/php-how-to-get-partial-output-when-script-is-executing