# Transfer-encoding in apache

Tags: php, apache, transfer-encoding

I have a couple of questions regarding transfer encoding.

-> Our backend scripts currently are taking ~ 500 ms, the HTML is generated in various parts/sections. So now if send data via chunks my page should by more responsive, is that reasoning correct?

-> Now from this ["Transfer-Encoding: chunked" header in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4809774/transfer-encoding-chunked-header-in-php). I found out that after each section I can add a flush() to send the data in chunks, with this technique in apache I can see the headed *transfer-encoding: chunked* added, is there a way for me to do that via web-server, i.e add that in apache if the content length exceeds a certain size, send that data in 1 chunk and so on.

Thanks in advance,
Nitesh