# Why does my site take so long to start a download?

Tags: php, performance, download

I have a server with hundreds of audio files on it (I own all of them by the way) where people can download them for free. I use the following PHP script to download the files:

```
<?php
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=audio.mp3');
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
readfile('Part1.mp3');
```

My viewers have complained, however, that it can take up to 30 seconds just for the download to begin. What can I do to improve the initialization speed of the download? Is it possible?

**Additional Info:**

My site is hosted by iPage.

Comment: I'm not sure about the legality to distribute "licensed" copy. But anyway... Hope you got your answer.

Comment: By that I mean I own all of the content I am offering.

Comment: Are you using Apache or other HTTP servers? What is the size of the files? Did you check the access log?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm kind of new to this kind of stuff. I know that the platform is Debian, the file sizes all range from 40mb to 80mb, and the access log is a long list of gibberish to me.

Comment: faster server, more ram, larger bandwidth, this kind of thing can consume some serious resources.

Comment: I think `readfile()` reads the whole file into memory and return. 40mb-80mb might mean something in a shared host. Try some small files and see if still slow.

Comment: An 18.4mb file took about 5 seconds, so yes I think you are right; I don't know another way to download the files though, so if someone could explain to me how to echo file segments or how to use mod_xsendfile (if iPage even offers that), that would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `readfile()` to read the entire file into memory and send it, read it in chunks, echo each chunk out as it's read, and flush after each. Better yet, see if mod_xsendfile or its equivalent is available, and use it to send the file.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=php+read+file+chunks Oh look, "How to serve big files through PHP"!

Comment: HTTP has chunked mode. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481858/how-to-make-php-generate-chunked-response) might help.