# Is it still possible to use output buffering, if so how?

Tags: php, output-buffering

I have been searching for a method to display content in a browser while a php script executes a fairly long while loop... using `ob_start()`, `flush()`,  `ob_flush()` and  `ob_end_flush()`. It failed.

While researching on [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php) I came across a user post that read:

> "As of August 2012, all browsers seem to show an all-or-nothing approach to buffering. In other words, while php is operating, no content can be shown."

The post goes on to say that all others posts are irrelevant. If this is true why has PHP.net displayed the necessary functions as deprecated? And if it isn't can some please me how to correctly implement output buffering for the simple script:

```
function simpleFunction() {
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
        $data = $externalJsondata;
        if($data == "True")
        {
        echo ("Output1");
        }
        else{
        echo ("Output2");           
        };
    };   
}

simpleFunction();
```

Comment: Are you looking for a universal solution (for a production environment) or just something that will work for a single server/client/browser combination?

Comment: what's the original problem? chances are OB isn't the solution you want. that was always a hack (in my experience) to work-around bad `header()`/`setcookie` calls. Didn't use it for much else.

Comment: Note that a common use of output buffering is to store output for further editing, rather than control of what gets sent to the browser for performance reasons. That purpose would remain valid.

Comment: I have an old hacked-together script that still uses OB to prevent "header already sent" errors. Don't know about the browser issues you mentioned.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make PHP generate Chunked response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481858/how-to-make-php-generate-chunked-response)

Comment: @DiegoAgulló, just checked. It works.

Comment: @MalcolmDiggs Quick hack, nothing long term, I found a solution though.

Comment: @lonesomeday Nope. THats not it. Just need to keep track of a script while its executing.

Comment: @BradChristie Solution found thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer/Hack provided by: [Joe Watkins](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1658631/joe-watkins)

```
function simpleFunction() {
if (!defined('STDOUT'))define('STDOUT', fopen("php://stdout", "w"));
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++) {
        $data = $externalJsondata;
        if($data == "True")
        {
        echo ("Output1");
        flush(STDOUT);
        }
        else{
        echo ("Output2");
        flush(STDOUT);        
        };
    };   
}

simpleFunction();
```

Thanks ;)