# How to disable Content-Length on LAMP

Tags: php, apache, http-headers, lamp

I need disable sending of Content-length an make other different settings in headers. How to perform that on LAMP configs?

At all, I need to make it like this

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Tue, 21 Jul 2015 05:58:49 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=97
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
```

But now I have this

```
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:ru-RU
Content-Length:2640
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 21 Jul 2015 05:58:44 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=95
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.4.41-0+deb7u1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you wish to accomplish this in PHP (I'm guessing from the headers that you are using PHP), you need to tell httpd that the encoding is chunked:

```
<?php
  header("Transfer-encoding: chunked");
  flush();
?>
```

This has been solved before on SO: [How to make PHP generate Chunked response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481858/how-to-make-php-generate-chunked-response)

While you may do this with PHP, I would advise you do not do this for static files, as that would kind of ruin the whole point of the protocol.